# Report Comparing two Subsets against Aggregate

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a report I'm writing which represents some customer 'worth' data.

This subset (let's call it T) is broken down into two sub-categories ('A', and 'B').  The issue I'm having is my limited knowledge of Math (or, I've been working on it too long.)

I have a result called 'a' from sub-category 'A' which represents the result of some function on the values from 'T' which are an element of 'A'.

The same applies to sub-category 'B' and result 'b'.  The sum of a + b = t, where t is the result of the same function on all of the values of 'T'.

What I'm trying to calculate are two ratios of 'A' and 'B' (let's call these ratios 'R<sub>a</sub>' and 'R<sub>b</sub>') based off of a known ratio as seen of set 'T' (R<sub>t</sub>).  The purpose of this ratio is to calculate another value, for 'A', 'B' and 'T' (Let's call these 'V<sub>a</sub>', 'V<sub>b</sub>', and 'V<sub>t</sub>') the sum of these two values will be V<sub>a</sub> + V<sub>b</sub> = V<sub>t</sub>.  R<sub>t</sub> and V<sub>t</sub> are known as are 'a' and 'b'.

R<sub>t</sub> = THEO<sub>s</sub> / (THEO<sub>s</sub> + THEO<sub>g</sub>)

I have tried to calculate the ratios using the same data from T that is present in both A and B, but the resulting V<sub>a</sub> + V<sub>b</sub> ≠ V<sub>t</sub>.  Does this likely mean that the way I am calculating the ratio for T, A, and/or B is incorrect?

I can't go into a whole lot more detail due to the sensitivity of the information, but needless to say 'a', and 'b' have to be weighted based off of their representation within T, this is likely the source of my problem and where I should try to find my answer...?

For Context:

There are 10 'Segments', 3 'States', on over 30,000 customers, so each single segment&state = one subset of 'T', which there are sub-categories 'A' and 'B'.  So effectively 30 total sets of T (T<sub>(1,1)</sub>, T<sub>(1,2)</sub>, T<sub>(1,3)</sub>, T<sub>(2, 1)</sub>, ..., T<sub>(10, 2)</sub>, T<sub>(10,3)</sub>)  For the sake of this question, I'm focusing on one version of T to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a complicated bit.  To project the worth of a given sector, it used distinct months for a given set, when the aggregate and subsequent subsets were calculated, because they added up to different month counts, creating a different 'worth' ratio, the aggregate didn't match ($V_{a} + V_{b} \neq V_{t}$).  Since the aggregate represents the full picture and a proper representation of the target audience, I had to approximate the relative time (vs the aggregate) the sub sets represented.

This also took into account response rates, which are known for the subsets and the aggregate's response rate is an aggregation of those.

So the sub-sets' worth figure had to be calculated off of the aggregate and neutralize the response rate that was figured into the aggregate.

$$
\begin{equation*}
W_{a} = \frac{\sum^{THEO}_{a}}{C_{a}*\frac{M_{t}*E_{t}}{C_{t}}}*E_{a}
\end{equation*}
$$

$$
E_{t} = \frac{E_{a} * C_{a} + E_{b} * C_{b}}{C_{t}}
$$
$C_{n} =$ The number of people within a set. Where:
$$
C_{a} + C_{b} = C_{t}
$$

$E_{n} =$ Estimated frequency at which a segment is to respond.  The aggregate months of a subset is not considered, because these subsets need to be a representation of the whole, and their 'counts' are already a part of the whole's data.